# Using group by with a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sequence

I need to run an insert on folderrsn but my select is returning duplicates of folderrsns so i was trying to do a group by but I get the:

> ORA-02287: SEQUENCE NUMBER NOT ALLOWED HERE

Is there a way to get around that or make my select statement more efficient?

```
INSERT INTO AMANDA.FOLDERFREEFORM(FREEFORMRSN, FREEFORMCODE, FOLDERRSN, C01, N01, N02, C02, C03, C04, D01, D02, D03, C05, C06)
SELECT AMANDA.FOLDERFREEFORMSEQ.NEXTVAL, 15030, F.FOLDERRSN, R.CATEGORY, R.REQUIRED, R.ELECTIVE, S.SCHOOL_NAME, C.CLASS_NAME, R.USED_FOR, R.DATE_USED, R.COURSE_DATE, RO.DATE_ROSTER_RECVD, R.CE_USED, I.INSTRUCTOR_NAME
FROM OREC_ROSTER_DTLS R
INNER JOIN AMANDA.FOLDER F ON F.CONVERSIONRSN = R.IND_SEQ_ID
INNER JOIN OREC_SCHOOLS S ON R.SCHOOL_NUMBER = S.SCHOOL_NUMBER
INNER JOIN OREC_COURSES C ON C.SCHOOL_NUMBER = S.SCHOOL_NUMBER
INNER JOIN OREC_ROSTERS RO ON R.ROSTER_NBR = RO.ROSTER_NBR
INNER JOIN OREC_INSTRUCTORS IS ON R.COURSE_INSTRUCTOR_NUMBER = IS.INSTRUCTOR_NUMBER
WHERE F.FOLDERTYPE = 'REAB'
Group by f.folderrsn;
```

Comment: throw it all in a subselect and do your sequence outside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your `select` query, without the sequence:

```
SELECT 15030, F.FOLDERRSN, R.CATEGORY, R.REQUIRED, R.ELECTIVE,
       S.SCHOOL_NAME, C.CLASS_NAME, R.USED_FOR, R.DATE_USED, R.COURSE_DATE, 
       RO.DATE_ROSTER_RECVD, R.CE_USED, I.INSTRUCTOR_NAME
FROM OREC_ROSTER_DTLS R
INNER JOIN AMANDA.FOLDER F ON F.CONVERSIONRSN = R.IND_SEQ_ID
INNER JOIN OREC_SCHOOLS S ON R.SCHOOL_NUMBER = S.SCHOOL_NUMBER
INNER JOIN OREC_COURSES C ON C.SCHOOL_NUMBER = S.SCHOOL_NUMBER
INNER JOIN OREC_ROSTERS RO ON R.ROSTER_NBR = RO.ROSTER_NBR
INNER JOIN OREC_INSTRUCTORS IS ON R.COURSE_INSTRUCTOR_NUMBER = IS.INSTRUCTOR_NUMBER
WHERE F.FOLDERTYPE = 'REAB'
Group by f.folderrsn;
```

This is not correct, because the `group by` only has one column but the `select` has many others.  I don't know what the intent of the `group by` is.  However, if you had a working query, you can add the sequence using a subquery:

```
select AMANDA.FOLDERFREEFORMSEQ.NEXTVAL, t.*
from (select . . .
      from . . .
      group by . . .
     ) t
```